# TinyMCE enable alpha channel in color picker from background color

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Is it possible to enable alpha values (rgba) in tinymce for the color picker?

I currently have this tinyMCE editor in my angular 15 web application:
[image]

I created it with the color_map attribute as you can see in this code:

```
modules = { branding: false,   
menubar: 'image insert format table',   
plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount',   toolbar:     'drpdwnHeading bold bullist numlist indent outdent table link image backcolor | style_formats',   style_formats: [     { title: 'Heading 3', format: 'h3' },     { title: 'Heading 4', format: 'h4' },     { title: 'Heading 5', format: 'h5' },   ],   
color_map: [     '#F27E00', // Red     
'#EB0000', // Green     
'#0000FF'  // Blue     // Add more color codes as needed   ];
```

But I wanted to have the colors with alpha values. As soon I paste in values with alpha channels e.g. #EB000026, it does not work anymore correctly.

I tried inserting it with and without hashtag as well as other attributes such as textcolor_map.

Does anybody know the solution to this problem?

Comment: I tried rgba values like "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)" and that didn't work, either. The first three values were used and the alpha value was ignored.